# iOS : How can I set frame of UILabel according to its text?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to develop a functionality that to set frame of `UILabel` according to its text means when text is change its frame is change? If yes, then please share any link or any idea to develop this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know needful **height** for some **width** you can use the code below:

```
NSString *yourString = @"My great text o0";
CGSize s = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
// s.height is your your height
```

For more information read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: hello how can i add button on o0 text frame position? any idea?

Comment: Programatically compute its location on the view and then add UIButton with custom style and clear background. Put it on "o0".

Comment: please give me code how can i compute location on the view?any idea?

Comment: Get size for text @"@"My great text " and for text @"My great text o0" and compute difference.

Comment: please give me that code to solve my issue b'coz its required

Answer (score 24):

```
label.text = @"some text of random length";
[label sizeToFit];
```

If the text might be more than 1 line, add `label.numberOfLines = 0;` before calling sizeToFit;

Comment: Thanks man, the sizeToFit just solved my problem: I was getting the label in the right position only at the second time i pressed the button.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
NSString *sample = @"...";

CGSize txtSz = [sample sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 16]];

CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(10,50, txtSz.width, txtSz.height);

yourLabel.frame = lblFrame;
```

Answer (score 5):

It's 2016 and `sizeWithFont` is long gone.

Now, and in Swift 3, use:

```
let text = "Random Text"
let size = (text as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)])
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to do this, but the `text as NSString` part concerns me.  Is there a more "native" swift way to do this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. In the future hopefully NSString will be completely bridged to String.